# [ViewController gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a simple scenario.

I push `myViewController` onto navigation stack.

`myViewController` is basically showing a collection view over entire screen. I added an additional `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on this collection view and set `myViewController` as its delegate. I am retaining a strong reference to that pan gesture recognizer inside `myViewController`.

When I tap Back, `myViewController` gets popped from the navigation stack and deallocated. The `myViewController`'s `dealloc` method gets called as it should. Up to this point everything works as expected.

Then I try to open the same `myViewController` like the first time and the crash occurs with the message:

```
[MyViewController gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

I have this method implemented in `myViewController` and it always returns `YES`. But this shouldn't even matter because no one should even be calling this method because none should have a strong reference to it. Obviously someone is still holding a weak reference since the `dealloc` method was called on the only instance that ever existed.

Not even the `init` method of the `MyViewController` gets called.

I tried to put the following code both in `dealloc` and in `viewWillDisappear`:

```
[self.myPanGestureRecognizer removeTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureAction:)];
    [self.collectionView removeGestureRecognizer:self.myPanGestureRecognizer];
    self.myPanGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
    self.myPanGestureRecognizer = nil;
```

But, it didn't change anything. Every time the same thing - myViewController gets `initialized` and displayed normally the first time. The second time I try to initialize and push, the exception occurs. Obviously, it is related to the pan gesture recognizer that I added, but I don't see how.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but I think it's related to another gesture recognizer. If I comment out the line used to add my custom gesture recognizer, I still get the error. Is there some other recognizer that is trying to pass a message to your deallocated view?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question ended up fixing my issue that was very similar:
[gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch persisting in deallocated view causing crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776596/gesturerecognizer-shouldreceivetouch-persisting-in-deallocated-view-causing-cras)

I was incorrectly setting self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate to self.

So even though the error reported from the NSZombie was in another class. It's gesture recognizer was not actually the culprit, it was my interactivePopGestureRecognizer.